# Retrieving BITS Version in C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, microsoft-bits

How can the the BITS (Background Intelligent Transfer Service) version be retrieved using C# .NET 4.0.

Comment: You must not have done much research before asking; first Google hit: [Determining the Version of BITS on a Computer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362837(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically retrieved the dll version of QMgr.dll in System32, since this is the dll for BITS.

```
const string bitsDll = "QMgr.dll";

var bitsDllInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Path
    .Combine(System.Environment.SystemDirectory, bitsDll));

updateDeliveryStatusRequest.BitsVersion = bitsDllInfo.FileVersion;
```